# Error running storybook - sh: 1: start-storybook: not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, storybook

I am facing error running **storybook**.... even on a clean installation.

```
 npm run storybook

> @ storybook /media/programmersedge/New_Volume/devs/demostorybook
> start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook

sh: 1: start-storybook: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ storybook: `start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ storybook script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am using the latest **storybook** version.
and my **node** version is *6.11.1* and **npm** version is *5.5.1*

I also tried installing storybook with **yarn** but I am facing the same problem
**yarn** version *1.3.2*

Comment: please check your pakage.json file and update your script run command. hope it's worked for you.

Comment: Have you tried installing dependencies first? **This maybe a cause due to the absence of `node_modules`**

Answer (score 17):

In most cases, you need to manually install `@storybook/cli` by running

```sh
# For npm
npm i -D @storybook/cli

# For yarn
yarn add -D @storybook/cli
```

Answer (score 10):

Update start and build scripts

```bash
"storybook": "sb dev",
"build-storybook": "sb build"
```

Comment: THIS is the only answer that actually got me past the command not found for version 7 (7.5.1). The fact [official docs](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/get-started/) rely on a template you might not want in your existing project is... distressing.

Answer (score 9):

#### Storybook v7

If you are facing this issue with Storybook 7, note that `start-storybook` and `build-storybook` were removed on [7.0.0-alpha.0 (June 7, 2022)](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md#700-alpha0-june-7-2022).

You should now use `storybook dev` or `storybook build`

Answer (score 8):

This error is due to the node_modules folder. If you delete that folder and run
`npm install`. it will work. Mostly due to cropped dependency linking  If you have configured a react app by yourself then the storyboard may need some other configuration. If you use create-react-app or react-npm-package-developer for React then it should work

Comment: I have already tried that. And as I have already mentioned ... I have also tried a clean install of `react-storybook` to confirm the issue. @mohanpd

Answer (score 3):

`npm i --save-dev @storybook/react` work for me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just make sure you are in the right folder. I know it sounds dumb, but when we are tired sometimes we commit dumb errors

Answer (score 0):

In my case restarting the system hasn't helped.
But **reinstalling** the application help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen after deleting my node_modules folder (rm -rf node_modules) and then re-installing.

I checked all the all versions of storybook (and anything related to storybook) in my package.json and made sure they all had exact versions at 6.5 like

```
 "storybook": "6.5.14",
 "@storybook/react": "6.5.16",
 "@storybook/addon-docs": "6.5.16",
```

After deleting and installing again, it worked!

Obviously do not upgrade if you want to remain on 6.5 and continue to use this start-storybook command

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to v7 just run migration script:

```bash
npx storybook@next automigrate
```