# Error follow storybook steps to create a libary with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, storybook

I'm try to create my libary follow this steps on [Storybook' site](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react/pt/get-started/):

```
npx create-react-app taskbox

cd taskbox

npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
```

When I run "npm start" the app works fine, but when I run "npm run storybook" I'm given this error on terminal:

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDkZM.png)

I'm using node 16.13.1

Help me please.

UPDATE

[A better image about the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w81dO.png)

Comment: Are you sure that is the error? because that doesnt looks real

Comment: Like a said, I'm just following the tutorial and when I run "npm run storybook" dont work, the terminal just stay"passing the letters"

Comment: above you said you ran ```npm start``` but now you are saying you ran ```npm run storybook```

Comment: I said: "When I run "npm start" the app works fine, but when I run "npm run storybook" I'm given this error on terminal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418007/error-running-storybook-sh-1-start-storybook-not-found) it seems that the following tactics worked:

```
npm i --save-dev @storybook/react
npm i -D @storybook/cli
```

Some also say you need to re install your node modules using:

```
npm install
```

and then using this instead after:
npm start-storybook

it seems like the tech has some faults and the bulk of the people said :

I kind of solved the issue. I think the issue was due to the file system. I restarted my system and then again reinstalled storybook. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I did what you recommended but I still have the same error :/

Comment: sorry to hear that i stay away from storybook sorry I couldnt be of any help

Comment: I just restarted my computer and tried again following these steps and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: great to hear! again maybe try staying away from this